# Nested Serializer Through Shared Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have three models. Two of them are connected to their "parent" via a foreign key. I need to create a serializer.

Here is my models.py

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 35, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 35, blank=True)


class Grade(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        "Student",
        null = True,
        on_delete = models.PROTECT,
    )
    grade = models.FloatField(null = True)


class Attendance(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        "Student",
        null = True,
        on_delete = models.PROTECT,
    )
    total_exabs = models.IntegerField(null = True)
```

Here is my serializers.py

```py
class StudentSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):
        def to_representation(self, student_obj):            
            return {
                "id": student_obj.pk,
                "first_name": student_obj.first_name,
                "last_name": student_obj.last_name,
            }

class GradeSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, grade_obj):
        return {
            "Grade PK": grade_obj.id,
            "Student": grade_obj.student.id,
            "Grade Value": grade_obj.grade,
        }

class AttendanceSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, attendance_obj):
        return {
            "student": attendance_obj.student.id,
            "total_exabs": attendance_obj.total_exabs,
        }
```

How do I create a fourth serializer that has attendance nested within grade? I essentially need every grade of a student to show their attendance as well.

This is what I am wanting

```
{"grade_id": "1",
"grade" : "0.73",
"student_id": "1",
"attendance": {"attendance_id": "1", "total_exabs": "7"}}
```

Thank you for any help you can offer! New to Django so thanks for your patience!

Comment: Whay are you using **`serializers.BaseSerializer`** ? instead of **`serializers.ModelSerializer`** ?

Comment: No reason! Is it better to use ModelSerializer?

Comment: Yeas.. Off course

Answer (score 0):

Your serializers.py may be, for example:

```
class GradeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=Grade
        fields=["student", "grade"]


class AttendanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = ["id", "total_exabs"]

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attendance_set = AttendanceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model=Student
        fields=["id","first_name", "last_name", "attendance_set"]
```

Then you can write:

```
>>> JSONRenderer().render(StudentSerializer(Student.objects.first()).data)
... b'{"id":1,"first_name":"st1f","last_name":"st1l","attendance_set":[{"id":1,"total_exabs":4},{"id":2,"total_exabs":5},{"id":3,"total_exabs":43}]}'
```

Update:
The grad info you may incorporate exactly the same:

```
class GradeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=Grade
        fields=["id", "grade"]

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    grade_set = GradeSerializer(many=True)
    attendance_set = AttendanceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model=Student
        fields=["id","first_name", "last_name", "attendance_set", "grade_set" ]
```

If each student has only one grade, you must have ForeignKey in the Student model for the grade, not in the Grade model for the student

Comment: This is great! How do I incorporate the grad info as well?

Comment: Thanks! Each student can have multiple grades though. How do I adjust for that?

Comment: I can’t have a foreign key in student I believe it has to be in grade

Comment: I've already writen in the update what you should do. What can't you do?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I need attendance to be "under" grade. As in I need it to look like this: {attendance_id: 1, total_exabs: 3, student_id: 1, grade_set: {grade_id: 7, grade: 0.73}}. Any thoughts?